# Java: how to find the minimum of an array (user input)

Tags: java

So far, this is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Please input numbers");
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = myScan.nextLine();
    String[] numbers = input.split(" ");
    int[] numbersInt = new int[numbers.length];


    int minNumber = numbersInt[0];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        numbersInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        if(numbersInt[i] < minNumber)
        {
            minNumber = numbersInt[i];
        }else if(minNumber < numbersInt[i])
        {
            minNumber = numbersInt[0];
        }
        }

        System.out.println(minNumber);

    }
    }
```

For example, if I type in the integers '20 15 60', I get the number "20" as the minimum. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `minNumber = numbersInt[0];` inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `minNumber` after parsing integers. also else if is not necessary. so this line should be moved :

```
int minNumber = numbersInt[0];
```

so your code would be like :

```
System.out.println("Please input numbers");
Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

String input = myScan.nextLine();
String[] numbers = input.split(" ");
int[] numbersInt = new int[numbers.length];

for(int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    numbersInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
}
int minNumber = numbersInt[0];
for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    if(numbersInt[i] < minNumber)
    {
        minNumber = numbersInt[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(minNumber);
```

although this is not the true way of reading a line of integers. you can do it like this :

```
Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
int n = myScan.nextInt();

System.out.println("Please input numbers");

int[] numbersInt = new int[n];
for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
{
    numbersInt[i] = myScan.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but with some bug. Firstly, move the  "int minNumber = numbersInt[0];" line after the first for loop. Secondly, remove the else part from the second for loop.

For your better under standing I am posting your code again :) with fixes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please input numbers");
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = myScan.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = input.split(" ");
        int[] numbersInt = new int[numbers.length];


        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbersInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
        }

        int minNumber = numbersInt[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbersInt[i] < minNumber) {
                minNumber = numbersInt[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(minNumber);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Solution 1**

The problem is just for two lines

1- move  `int minNumber = numbersInt[0]` (Put it after first `for`)

2-Delete below snippet in the second `for`

```
  else if(minNumber < numbersInt[i])
        {

          minNumber = numbersInt[0];

        }
```

> Finally, your code can be as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please input numbers");
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = myScan.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = input.split(" ");
        int[] numbersInt = new int[numbers.length];


        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbersInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
        }

        //Changed
        int minNumber = numbersInt[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {

            if (numbersInt[i] < minNumber) {
                minNumber = numbersInt[i];
            } 
            //Changed (deleted)
        }

        System.out.println(minNumber);

    }
```

> **Solution 2**

I would recommend this code for your scenario

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter numbers, if you wanna stop just enter non numeric input");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Get input numbers and add it to the list
        List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            numberList.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }

        //Get the minimum of numberList
        System.out.println("Min :" + Collections.min(numberList));

    }
```

Comment: If you're going to use a solution from the standard library, `Collections.min(numberList)` would be simpler and more efficient than sorting.